# Cannot change button location when define style in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need my button (which is defined in Logout component) to be near to the Nav item.

When I call it, it would put it at the middle of the screen and won't consider the top and left defined in style.

This is Logout component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class LogOutButton extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    store: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.onLogout();
  };

  render() {
    const LogoutButtonStyle = {
     color: 'black',
     background: '#b7e1f7',
     height: 50px,
     width: 100px,
     left: 10,
     top: 10,
     display:'inline-block'
}

    return <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick} style = {LogoutButtonStyle}>Back to Microsoft Give</button>;
 }
}
```

Also, if I remove the 'top' and 'left', the button's location would still be the same.

This is the WholeScreen component in which I add logout component into:

```
  render(){
    .......

    return(
      <div className="WholeScreen">
        <div>
           <Nav bsStyle="pills" activeKey={this.state.year} onSelect={this.handleSelect} >
          {buttons}
        <LogoutButtonComponent onLogout={this.onLogoutClick}/>
        </Nav>
        </div>
        <div>          
      <YearlySummary year={this.state.year} yearData={yearData}/>
        </div>
      </div> 
     );
    }
  }
```

I put the logout button inside the same  with the navigation, but it would put the logout button at the center and not next to it.

Comment: if you want to set the top and left then first set the position of the button to absolute or fixed.

Comment: I added     position: 'absolute' inside logout component, still did not work

Comment: have you tried adding display: inline-block, and giving the button height and width with some units like px, rem, em?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean, can you please edit my question with your answer ?